Should we break up the "memory" tag?
We currently have one tag for all things memory.
Do we want to keep it this way, or do we want to break this tag up into multiple tags, E.G. short-term-memory and long-term-memory? If so, what categories do we want?

IMO at least long-term-memory, short-term-memory, and working-memory are distinct enough and well researched enough to deserve their own tags. I'm more on the fence as to whether encoding and mnemonic require tags, but I think they're okay as well.
For casual interest I get the memory might be a nice tag to browse, but they're distinct concepts with complex interactions.

I like this. I dare say we blacklist [tag:memory] as well, forcing people to choose a more distinct tag.

@JoshGitlin not 100% sure about that...but I'm not really opposed either. It's got more merit than a Psychology tag but I'm not sure it's useful to leave the more general tag on or not.

@BenBrocka it has more merit than the cognitive-psychology tag.

@ArtemKaznatcheev not really, cognitive psychology is a well defined field, you just don't like the tag, and more relevantly, how it's used :P

But by that same argument, psychology is a well-defined field...

@ArtemKaznatcheev psych is, but it would apply to about half the site, and there are more relevant and helpful sub-fields. That's also the case with memory, but not always the case with cog psych.

Memory has 31 questions, I don't think it is being abused (like cognitive-psychology is). I don't see a need to separate it into multiple tags. I definitely don't see a need to black-list it.
Just because long-term-memory and short-term-memory operate in different ways, doesn't mean they need different tags. If we do black-list memory because it has multiple different concepts under it, then what kind of precedent are we setting? How many concepts does cognitive-psychology have under it?
